# Fill in suggestion in search without triggering search

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

On my iPhone I find that the google suggestion list has a large portion of my search term already and I'd like to use a suggestion without having to type it. Is it possible to select one of the suggestions and have it fill up my partially typed term but without triggering the search?

What happens now is it automatically executes the search when I choose a suggestion even though I want to add more to it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without jailbreaking, this is not possible. If you jailbreak, you can install **Platinum** which adds an *i* button to the right of each suggestion which can be tapped to add the suggestion to the search without the search taking place.